# Argument of type 'EventHandler<T[K]>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'EventHandler<T[keyof T]>'

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

```
Argument of type 'EventHandler<T[K]>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'EventHandler<T[keyof T]>'.
```

```js
export type EventType = string | symbol;
export type Events = Record<EventType, unknown[]>;
export type EventHandler<T = unknown[]> = (args: T) => void;
export class EventEmitter<T extends Events> {
    private events = new Map<keyof T, EventHandler<T[keyof T]>>();
    public on<K extends keyof T>(key: K, handler: EventHandler<T[K]>) {
        this.events.set(key, handler);
    }
}
```

Why `T[K]` is not assignable to `T[keyof T]`?

Logically, `K` should be part of `keyof T`

Comment: Which line generates the error?

Comment: @codecubed the line `this.events.set(key, handler)`. To be precise, the `handler` argument.

Answer (score 0):

A newer version of typescript seems to show a more detailed error:

```
Argument of type 'EventHandler<T[K]>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'EventHandler<T[keyof T]>'.
  Type 'T[keyof T]' is not assignable to type 'T[K]'.
    Type 'keyof T' is not assignable to type 'K'.
      'keyof T' is assignable to the constraint of type 'K', but 'K' could be instantiated with a different subtype of constraint 'string | number | symbol'.
        Type 'string | number | symbol' is not assignable to type 'K'.
          'string | number | symbol' is assignable to the constraint of type 'K', but 'K' could be instantiated with a different subtype of constraint 'string | number | symbol'.
            Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'K'.
              'string' is assignable to the constraint of type 'K', but 'K' could be instantiated with a different subtype of constraint 'string | number | symbol'.ts(2345)
```

This version seems to work:

```js
export type EventType = string | symbol;
export type Events = Record<EventType, unknown[]>;
export type EventHandler<T = unknown[]> = (args: T) => void;

export class EventEmitter<T extends Events, K extends keyof T = keyof T> {
    private events = new Map<K, EventHandler<T[K]>>();
    public on(key: K, handler: EventHandler<T[K]>) {
        this.events.set(key, handler);
    }
}
```

Here is why that makes a difference: Consider the following code:

```
export type EventType = string | symbol;
export type Events = Record<EventType, unknown[]>;
export type EventHandler<T = unknown[]> = (args: T) => void;

export class EventEmitter<T extends Events> {
    private events: Map<keyof T, EventHandler<T[keyof T]>> = new Map<symbol, EventHandler<T[keyof T]>>();
    public on<K extends keyof T>(key: K, handler: EventHandler<T[K]>) {
        this.events.set(key, handler);
    }
}

let emitter = new EventEmitter();
emitter.on<string>("a", () => { });
```

The `events` member's key is `keyof T`, which means it is one of either `string` or `symbol`. It does not guarantee which one. In our case it's `symbol`, which is totally fine.

So if you now call the `on()` function with the type `string`, that's also completely legal, because `string` is one of `string | symbol`. But of course, you can't use `string` as a key for `events`, because the key type of `events` is `symbol`.

And that is exactly what the typescript error tells you. Both `K` and `keyof T` have to be either `string` or `symbol`, but they *do not have to be the same one*. `K` could be a `string`, and `keyof T` could be a `symbol`.

My 'corrected' version works because the type of `K` is now known for the entire class and cannot vary between parts of the class.

---

### Simplified version of the problem

Look at the following code:

```js
type NumberOrString = string | number;

class Container<K extends NumberOrString> {
    public hello(value: K) {
        console.log(value);
    }

    public hello2<K2 extends NumberOrString>(value: K2) {
        this.hello(value);
    }
}
```

This one yields a very similar error:

```
Argument of type 'K2' is not assignable to parameter of type 'K'.
  'K2' is assignable to the constraint of type 'K', but 'K' could be instantiated with a different subtype of constraint 'NumberOrString'.ts(2345)
```

And here it should be much more obvious. Both `K` and `K2` are from the same type `NumberOrString`, but they don't have to be the same sub-type.
It's perfectly legal to use the class like this:

```
let c = new Container<string>();
c.hello2<number>(10);
```

Where `hello2<number>(10)` would internally call `hello<string>(10)`. Which of course would violate the typing constraints.

---

### Potential bug in typescript

For some reason, this seems to work:

```
export type EventType = string | symbol;
export type Events = Record<EventType, unknown[]>;
export type EventHandler<T = unknown[]> = (args: T) => void;

export class EventEmitter<T extends Events> {
    private events: Map<keyof T, EventHandler<T[keyof T]>> = new Map<symbol, EventHandler<T[keyof T]>>();
    public on(key: keyof T, handler: EventHandler<T[keyof T]>) {
        this.events.set(key, handler);
    }
}

let emitter = new EventEmitter<Record<string, unknown[]>>();
emitter.on("10", () => { });
```

I have no idea why, though.
Assuming that this is a bug, I opened a [ticket on the typescript bug tracker](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/45622).